# Risk of old pesticides in former Soviet countries

Tags: international-travel, health, environment

To what extent do remaining hazardous pesticides (POPs like DDT, etc.) in the soil, groundwater, rivers etc. pose a current health risk in the food (products from supermarkets, food in restaurants cooked with water, etc.) and water in former Soviet countries?

Comment: Are you expecting this to differ much from non Soviet countries? The use of those pesticides was commen in many more countries, like most that were in the NATO block at the time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don’t think it’s on topic, and it reads like a homework question.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows. When Germany was reunited in 1989, many western companies bought or invested in eastern companies and began to renovate them.  To their horror they found a lot of toxic waste sites that weren't documented anywhere or that no one knew about (or pretended to not to know about). Some still pop up to this day.

Comment: @Hilmar I have 27 [superfund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfund) sites just in the country I live in.  This is definetly not something from the distant past.

Comment: Actually, this appears very much to be an issue in the former Soviet countries. I am not sure it is permitted to share links; you can do a search on the topic ("toxic pesticides former Soviet countries", for example) and you will find several general articles as well as more specialized papers by organizations attempting to assess and address the issue. Of course these pesticides were used in other countries, but the figure is around 43% of all of the remaining such pesticides are in the former Soviet countries. I have read the papers; I want to know the current practical health impact.

Comment: @PeterM: Of course you do but these are generally KNOWN, i.e. they can be managed and avoided. The stuff in the east is UNKNOWN, so you might live on a toxic waste dump without knowing it. Record keeping on this type of thing was very poor in East Germany and some existing records were deliberately destroyed.

Comment: @Hilmar if you think deliberate destuction of records is an issue, enjoy the ride to the US localities https://theconversation.com/the-nuclear-arms-races-legacy-at-home-toxic-contamination-staggering-cleanup-costs-and-a-culture-of-government-secrecy-210262 ... yes, you may know where in the map +-5 miles is the polluted sites, but the exact locations is unknown in EastGermany as well in the US ... and that is what makes the cleanup extremely expensive.

Comment: @Hilmar and enjoy the history of clean West Germany: you will not find many WGerman toxic dump sites ... if you look only in WGermany
https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/contemporary-european-history/article/abs/big-clean-the-death-ship-and-the-hazardous-waste-trade-between-west-germany-and-turkey-19871988/33E6B89869031F82AC68409CDDE79B18

Answer (score 4):

Hazardous pesticides *in food and water* that you might eat and drink are not a concern in any former Soviet countries that I know of. More specifically:

Water - prefer bottled water, water from coolers, filtered water or, failing that, boiled water. Locals do not usually drink tap water, even though it may be OK. Washing hands and vegetables with tap water, brushing teeth with tap water is completely normal.

Food - apply common sense. It should be not super shabby, not super exotic and something that locals may also buy and eat.

With regards to toxic pesticides:

- It's been more than 30 years since the Soviet Union for any chemicals to cycle out and not be an immediate danger.
- More affluent countries usually took some effort to regulate the toxicity of stuff they use, less affluent countries had periods of subsistence farming with not much chemicals used in agriculture at all.
- In general, Soviet countries has mostly moved to whatever practices the rest of the world does, since it is often both cheaper and more efficient. So the chemical makeup will be no different than in any other country of comparable HDI.

It is perhaps possible that you can walk into an unguarded toxic chemicals dump here and there, but it would still usually require doing some un-touristy things (like deviating from the common paths and delving into a forsaken industrial area, for example). Everywhere where locals walk, should be OK, especially on tourist time frame.

Answer (score 3):

Use of pesticides seems to be [less](https://www.worldometers.info/food-agriculture/pesticides-by-country/) in post-Soviet countries than in many Western countries:

- Russia, Azerbaijan 0.2 kg/hectare
- Tajikistan 0.3
- Kyrgyzstan 0.4
- Kazakhstan 0.5
- Armenia, Belarus 0.6
- Estonia 1.0
- Latvia 1.1
- Lithuania 1.4
- Moldova 1.8
- Ukraine 2.3
- Turkmenistan 4.9

(Uzbekistan
and Georgia are not listed)

Compare to major Western European agricultural-producing countries:

- France, Spain 3.6
- Germany 4.0
- Italy 6.1
- Netherlands 7.9

USA is 2.5, Canada is 2.4, UK is 3.2,

Comment: And then there are countries such as Costa Rica (22.5), El Salvador (6), Guatemala (10.0), Honduras (4.2) that still suffer from the economic exploitation of the past. [Banana republic/Pesticides -  Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_republic#Pesticides)